# "Remaining Credits" in Azure Free Trial Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, subscription

I have three days left of my free trial. I still have a lot of "remaining credits". Do I still have those credits after the free trial, so that I can keep my stuff up and running by switching subscription to the "Pay-as-you-go" option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as soon as your trial duration runs out, your remaining credits will cease to exist. It is the same principle with monthly credits (like you get from MSDN, MS Partner Network, etc.), those are only valid during the month they were given for.

Comment: That sucks :( I didn't know that when I started mines either. I have 9 days left with over 190 credit still on account. Didn't have time after work like i thought i was going to have to learn/play with Azure...